# Как передать window.open url в переменной?

Tags: javascript

Как забрать значение атрибута href у ссылки и передать переменной в url.

```
var href = document.getElementById('price_list_download');
var ten = href.getAttribute('href');
window.open('ten', '_blank');
```

Comment: `window.open()` с большой вероятностью будет заблокирован.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто переменную `ten` не надо в кавычках, а то это принимается просто как строка.

```js
var href = document.getElementById('price_list_download');
var ten = href.getAttribute('href');
window.open(ten, '_blank');
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" id="price_list_download">stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал об этом

Answer (score 0):

Получаем аттрибут `href`

```
var href = document.getElementById('price_list_download').href;
```

И передаем в урл

```
window.location.href = href;
```